# Why create public wrappers to private members in a class?

Tags: c#, .net

I've always had this question, but I've blindly followed on so far.

This is from a piece of example code:

Why do this:

```
public class EmployeeInfo
{
    int _EmpNo;
    public virtual int EmpNo
    {
        get { return _EmpNo; }
        set { _EmpNo = value; }
    }

    string _EmpName;
    public virtual string EmpName
    {
        get { return _EmpName; }
        set { _EmpName = value; }
    }
}
```

when there's nothing additional, such as calculations or validations, being done during getting/setting?

Will this suffice?

```
public class EmployeeInfo
{
    public int EmpNo { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
}
```

Also, why `virtual` for the public member wrappers?

Comment: 1) You don't have to use private members if all you're doing is allowing other classes to read and set the value from the property.
2) Virtual keyword allows child classes to override the property.

Comment: slapping virtual on everything that's public is generally a bad idea, not because it changes functionality but because it means that people are being lazy when they consider how they should implement inheritance

Answer (score 5):

> Why do this?

There's really no reason to since the addition of auto-implemented properties in C# 3.0.  It could be legacy code that hasn't been changed, old habits, or keeping consistency with pre-C# 3 code.

> Will this suffice?

No - you've converted the `virtual` properties to non-virtual.  So they are not completely equivalent.

The equivalent would be

```
public class EmployeeInfo
{
    public virtual int EmpNo { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmpName { get; set; }
}
```

> Also, why virtual for the public member wrappers?

So that a derived class *can* override the logic for the properties - to add validation, change notification, etc.

> When does the shortened form actually have an impact?

When the backing fields are referenced by the internal code of the class (which can be detected at compile-time), or when they're accessed by reflection (which cannot be detected until run-time, or via static code analysis).

An "auto-implemented" property actually gets a backing field created by the compiler, so in that sense they're equivalent if the only place the backing field is referenced is within the property code.

Comment: Would `public virtual int EmpNo { get; set; }` be equivalent?

Comment: Please add more detail? When does the shortened form actually have an impact?

Answer (score 3):

You have two questions. First is changing properties to [auto implemented properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), they should be equal, but you removed `virtual` keyword, that makes them different.

So, what is `virtual`. That keyword will allow derived classes to override the `get/set` for the said property.

See: [virtual C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or
>   event declaration and allow for it to be **overridden in a derived
>   class**.

Your class with auto-implemented properties would be equal if you have:

```
public class EmployeeInfo
{
    public virtual int EmpNo { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmpName { get; set; }
}
```

Later you can override a property and leave the other to maintain the parent behaviour, like:

```
public class ManagerInfo : EmployeeInfo
{
    private int _EmpNo;

    public override int EmpNo
    {
        get { return _EmpNo; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 100) throw new Exception("EmpNo for manager must be greater than 100");

            _EmpNo = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends if you want to see the field publicly or not,

if your only going to use the field inside the declaring class then  you don't need to wrap it in a property, its only if you need to expose it publicly or down the inheritance tree that you should have the property

```
public string EmpName { get; set; }
```

is just a compiler short cut to

```
private string _EmpName;
public string EmpName { 
    get{ return _EmpName;}
    set(_EmpName = value; }
}
```

they are functionally identical.
However there are things that the short cut wont let you do, for example you want to raise an event when the property changes.

there there is also your use of Virtual which is an inheritance modifier
Virtual instructs the code that it needs to look DOWN the inheritance tree for a newer implementation. 
so in

```
class A
{
    public string Data
    {
        get{return "A";}
    }
    public virtual string VData
    {
        get{return "A";}
    }
}
class B:A
{
    public new string Data
    {
        get{return "B";}
    }

    public override string VData
    {
        get{return "B";}
    }
}
```

then if you do

```
A obj = new B();
obj.Data; //return A
obj.VData; //return B
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to say in the first two paragraphs. There's no attribute. If you mean field, you can have public fields, virtual fields and private properties just as well.

Comment: sorry slipped into to my generic OO, in generic OO classes have attributes and methods, flied is a c# specific term

Comment: Exposing fields as public or protected is very bad practice as the entire concept of OO is that the Class is in control of the data it contains that means any access to data has to be via a class exposed method or property

Comment: Yeah sure, but then explain _that_ in your answer instead of _"if you don't want to see it publicly then you don't need any get or set"_, as the latter sounds pretty vague.

Comment: seems simple enough to me if your using it only inside the declaring class then generally there is no need to wrap it in a private property

Comment: I'm not arguing with _that_, I'm saying that how you phrase that is pretty unclear.

Comment: like i said seems pretty clear to me, but then i know what i meant it to say.. adjusted the word to hopefully improve the clarity

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code in this form:

```
$type _$var;
public virtual $type $var
{
    get { return _$var; }
    set { _$var = value; }
}
```

Was generated using a tool, template or snippet. As habits hardly ever change and tools, templates and snippets hardly ever get updated, I guess they were created before auto-implemented properties (`public $type $var { get; set; }`) were introduced to the C# language.

For the code you show, it's perfectly valid to have the equivalent:

```
public virtual $type $var { get; set; }
```

As you can override the auto-implemented property and add a backing field, validation and whatever when required.

Answer (score 0):

The expanded form is the traditional way to do it:

```
public class MyClass
{
    int _myInt;

    virtual public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _myInt;
        }
        set
        {
            _myInt = value;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the shorter form is called "auto properties", introduced in C# 3.0.

```
public class MyClass
{
    virtual public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

These code blocks are equivalent. This is a good practice for keeping your code concise.

One thing to consider: You aren't able to make the internal variable `protected` with auto properties, so if you create a derived class and `override` your property, you'll need to use `base.MyProperty` to access it, or use the expanded form.